# Is there any way to serialize an instance of Optional<T> with Jackson?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

Jackson is demanding the `public` modifier on a no-arg constructor, while jdk8's `Optional` provides only static methods. What are the possible workarounds? And in general, if I have to use a a 3rd party library providing classes following this pattern, what should I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838039/jackson-3rd-party-class-with-no-default-constructor ?

Comment: @BrianRoach, I still don't get how to make use of that in case of a generic type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Jackson does NOT require a public no-arg constructor; any access level (even `private`) will work. But it does require a no-arg constructor if no custom deserializer is provided.

What is needed for new types, in general are extension modules. There are actually plans to add a "JDK8 module", since core Jackson only requires 1.6 currently, and baseline is unlikely to move in near future. But adding support for new types should be relatively easy: Jackson Guava datatype module (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-guava) for example, adds support for Guava's `optional`. You may be able to copy deserializer from there in the meantime, use it via `SimpleModule` you define.

Comment: Thank you, this link is a helpful one. Since there is no significant difference, I'm going to implement something like that while there is no support for this stuff out-of-the-box.

Comment: Here's the issue, for any newcomers https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/494

Answer (score 0):

`Optional` support has since been added to Jackson, and can be used by adding [`Jdk8Module`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/latest/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jdk8/Jdk8Module.html) to the `ObjectMapper`:

```java
JsonMapper objectMapper =
        JsonMapper.builder().addModule(new JavaTimeModule()).build();
```