# JSON deserialisation using Jackson: No suitable constructor found for type - providing default constructor or annotate constructor is imposible

Tags: java, json, jackson

I used Jackson ObjectMapper to serialise object hierarchy to json String. After that I wanted to deserialize the object back. I got exception as below.

The important thing is that **`APINewDealArrangementImpl` class hierarchy is out of the scope of my changes** - it is part of external library. In this case **I'm not able to implement default constructor nor use `@JsonCreator` annotion**.

How can I avoid "No suitable constructor found" Exception? Is it possible to conquer this problem using some custom `TypeResolverBuilder` implementation or other functionalities in Jackson API? Thanks for help.

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.tzero.api.transactions.TransactionState]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@57ac3379; line: 4, column: 5] (through reference chain: com.tzero.api.java.transactions.APINewDealArrangementImpl["state"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializer.java:746)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:683)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2732)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1863)
```

Comment: This is a good use case for [Jackson Mixins](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations)

Comment: @GarisMSuero this is not a duplicate since I cannot implement default insructor for the serialised class. As described above, the reson is that I am not able modify the class - it is closed source.

Comment: This question is NOT a duplicate, and should be marked up.  The original question assumes one can modify the object, whereas this question assumes the object is third party and unchangeable.

Comment: @TylerH could you please remove duplicate mark from this question as stated above?

Comment: A better option is to use Google Gson. Which works perfectly even if we don't have default constructor. 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-json-string-to-java-object-using-gson/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a "mixin" to provide the annotations on a *different* class. Which is a bit odd, but very useful.

```
@Test
public void mixin_to_specify_creator() throws Exception {
    TargetData target = mapper.addMixIn(TargetData.class, TargetDataMixin.class).reader(TargetData.class)
            .<TargetData> readValue("{\"name\":\"the name\", \"description\":\"the description\"}");
    assertThat(target.name, equalTo("the name"));
    assertThat(target.description, equalTo("the description"));
}

public static class TargetData {
    private final String name;
    private final String description;

    public TargetData(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }
}

public static abstract class TargetDataMixin {
    @JsonCreator
    public TargetDataMixin(@JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("description") String description) {
    }
}
```

So here there are no Jackson annotations on TargetData, the annotations are taken from TargetDataMixin (and the implementation of TargetDataMixin is totally ignored)