# Jackson objectMapper readValue

Tags: jackson, objectmapper

Using Jackson `ObjectMapper.readValue()` to read a JSON String into a java object.

The particular java class does not have a default constructor neither can be edited i.e, annotations `@JSONCreator` or `@JSONProperty` cannot be added.
Hence getting the exception `no suitable constructor found for type`.

How can this be tackled?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Jackson's mixin feature](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations) to externally add annotations to a class.
See [This question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080217/json-deserialisation-using-jackson-no-suitable-constructor-found-for-type-pro) for more details