# How to deserialize Spring's ResponseEntity with Jackson ObjectMapper (probably with using @JsonCreator and Jackson mixins)

Tags: java, spring, jackson, deserialization, mixins

The class `ResponseEntity` [doesn't have a default constructor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html). 
Then in order to deserialize it with objectMapper I decided to use the approach given by araqnid in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30087522/5572007).
Shortly - it needs to use mixin feature of Jackson coupled with @JsonCreator.

In my case (with ResponseEntity) it doesn't work out yet due to different reasons.

My test method looks like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ResponseEntity<Object> build = ResponseEntity.ok().build();

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.addMixIn(ResponseEntity.class, ResponseEntityMixin.class);

    String s = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(build);
    ResponseEntity<Object> result = objectMapper.readValue(s, ResponseEntity.class);

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Firstly, I tried to use the shortest constructor for mixin:

```java
public abstract static class ResponseEntityMixin {
    @JsonCreator
    public ResponseEntityMixin(@JsonProperty("status") HttpStatus status) {
    }
}
```

In this case I got an assertion error since `ResponseEntity` has this line of code inside it's constructor:

```
Assert.notNull(status, "HttpStatus must not be null");
```

Then I switched the mode of @JsonCreator to `DELEGATING` but in this case I got another exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `org.springframework.http.HttpStatus` from String "headers": value not one of declared Enum instance names: [UPGRADE_REQUIRED, UNAVAILABLE_FOR_LEGAL_REASONS, SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE, CHECKPOINT, LOCKED, METHOD_FAILURE, FAILED_DEPENDENCY, UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, PROCESSING, PROXY_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED, METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, GONE, MULTIPLE_CHOICES, GATEWAY_TIMEOUT, ACCEPTED, TEMPORARY_REDIRECT, INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, URI_TOO_LONG, LOOP_DETECTED, PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE, EXPECTATION_FAILED, MOVED_TEMPORARILY, REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE, NOT_EXTENDED, CREATED, RESET_CONTENT, BAD_GATEWAY, CONFLICT, VARIANT_ALSO_NEGOTIATES, NETWORK_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED, NOT_FOUND, LENGTH_REQUIRED, INSUFFICIENT_SPACE_ON_RESOURCE, NO_CONTENT, OK, FOUND, SEE_OTHER, BANDWIDTH_LIMIT_EXCEEDED, REQUEST_HEADER_FIELDS_TOO_LARGE, PERMANENT_REDIRECT, NOT_ACCEPTABLE, MOVED_PERMANENTLY, REQUEST_TIMEOUT, UNAUTHORIZED, USE_PROXY, IM_USED, ALREADY_REPORTED, PARTIAL_CONTENT, PRECONDITION_FAILED, REQUEST_URI_TOO_LONG, BAD_REQUEST, INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE, CONTINUE, NON_AUTHORITATIVE_INFORMATION, REQUESTED_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE, UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE, I_AM_A_TEAPOT, HTTP_VERSION_NOT_SUPPORTED, SWITCHING_PROTOCOLS, NOT_MODIFIED, NOT_IMPLEMENTED, TOO_MANY_REQUESTS, DESTINATION_LOCKED, PAYMENT_REQUIRED, FORBIDDEN, PRECONDITION_REQUIRED, MULTI_STATUS]
 at [Source: (String)"{"headers":{},"body":null,"statusCode":"OK","statusCodeValue":200}"; line: 1, column: 2]
```

Also I tried to use the all-arguments constructor of `ResponseEntity` but it was also unsuccessful because of problems with `MultiValueMap` deserialization (but I believe that if I fixed it then it would finally bring me to the same problem as described above).

Could anyone help me solving this problem? Maybe it's impossible to use mixins in this case at all?

If you know the another approaches how to deserialize `ResponseEntity` with Jackson - please give them too.

Here is the source code of my tests: https://github.com/amseager/responseentitydeserialization

Comment: This is an extremely well defined question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `MixIns` is a good way to solve it:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ResponseEntity<Object> entity = ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .header("header", "value")
                .body("Everything is OK!");

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.addMixIn(ResponseEntity.class, ResponseEntityMixin.class);
        objectMapper.addMixIn(HttpStatus.class, HttpStatusMixIn.class);

        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(entity);
        TypeReference ref = new TypeReference<ResponseEntity<Object>>() {
        };
        ResponseEntity<Object> result = objectMapper.readValue(json, ref);
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println(result.equals(entity));
    }
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class ResponseEntityMixin {
    @JsonCreator
    public ResponseEntityMixin(@JsonProperty("body") Object body,
                               @JsonDeserialize(as = LinkedMultiValueMap.class) @JsonProperty("headers") MultiValueMap<String, String> headers,
                               @JsonProperty("statusCodeValue") HttpStatus status) {
    }
}

class HttpStatusMixIn {

    @JsonCreator
    public static HttpStatus resolve(int statusCode) {
        return HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT;
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
<200 OK OK,Everything is OK!,[header:"value"]>
```

and
`true` which means source and deserialised objects are the same.

Comment: Big thanks! So it was a bit more complicated task. Also I made some mistakes, need to dig deeper into the subject.

Comment: I have a similar scenario where I need to convert a json response string to ResponseEntity<String> I tried the above solution but I am getting the following error:

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)

Comment: @Poojasingh, I gues, you do not have to deserialise it to `ResponseEntity<String>`. You probably can just create a new object using some factory method: `ResponseEntity.of(json)`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `ResponseEntityDecoder` to able to parse `ResponseEntity` :

```
Feign.Builder builder = Feign.builder()
            .encoder(new JacksonEncoder(objectMapper))
            .decoder(new ResponseEntityDecoder(new JacksonDecoder(objectMapper)))
```

Then it should work

Comment: thanks but I think the question wasn't related to Feign