# How to get Jackson to use a Google Guice Injector to create instances?

Tags: java, json, jackson, guice, jackson-modules

We use Google Guice for DI (mostly with constructor injection) and Jackson for object serialization to/from JSON. As such we build our object graph through Guice Modules.

How do we provide/instruct Jackson to use our pre-built Guice Injector? Or it's own injector based on a Guice Module we provide? My preference is to provide it the injector because we already have means to control which module is used based on the environment/configuration we want to run in.

Here's a unit test:

```
public class Building {

    @JsonIgnore
    public final ElectricalProvider electricalProvider;

    public String name;

    @Inject
    Building(ElectricalProvider electricalProvider){
         this.electricalProvider = electricalProvider;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

}

public interface ElectricalProvider {}

public class SolarElectricalProvider implements  ElectricalProvider{}

@Test
public void testJacksonGuice() throws IOException {

    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new Module() {
      @Override public void configure(Binder binder) {
           binder.bind(ElectricalProvider.class).to(SolarElectricalProvider.class);
      }
    });

    Building building1 = injector.getInstance(Building.class);
    building1.setName("test building");

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    byte[] buildingJsonBytes = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(building1);

    Building building2 = objectMapper.readValue(buildingJsonBytes, Building.class);

    assertThat(building1, is(equalTo(building2)));
    assertThat(building2.electricalProvider, is(instanceOf(SolarElectricalProvider.class)));

}
```

That when run generates this exception `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException`, with this message: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class Building]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)

After a bit of googling, I came across the [jackson-module-guice](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-guice) project but it doesn't appear to be what we need or doesn't provide as to how to accomplish what we need to do.

Answer (score -2):

Well, i think your approach is anti-pattern. You should serialize and deserialize only POJO object without any business logic and any further dependencies like services, repositories and so on. Could you show your `Building` class? What's in the constructor?

You should split your `Building` class into `Service` and `Domain` layers. The `Service` layer would use `Domain` and there you should inject all dependencies. The `Domain` layer would be only POJO bean with default constructor, no final fields and only getter/setter methods.

If you need to use final properties and constructor initialization you have few options as mentioned in [Jackson 3rd Party Class With No Default Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838039/jackson-3rd-party-class-with-no-default-constructor)

Comment: I disagree that I should split the logic as you suggest. One of the key aspects of object orientated design/development/programming is encapsulation of data and logic associated with the particular object into the object itself.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Would be best as a comment.