# Parsing kotlin Pair with nullable parameters fails on empty json

Tags: kotlin, jackson, objectmapper

I've found that `ObjectMapper` tends to omit nullable parameters.

Following expression:

```
objectMapper.readValue<Pair<String?,Long?>>("{}")
```

causes:

```
caused by com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.MissingKotlinParameterException: 
Instantiation of [simple type, class kotlin.Pair] 
value failed for JSON property first due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator 
parameter first which is a non-nullable type at [Source: (String)"{}"; line: 1, column: 2] 
(through reference chain: kotlin.Pair["first"])
```

while:

```
data class InternalPair(val first: String?, val second: Long?)

objectMapper.readValue<InternalPair>("{}")
```

works fine.

Is it intended or is it a bug?

Comment: Take a look on similar question [Jackson 3rd Party Class With No Default Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838039/jackson-3rd-party-class-with-no-default-constructor). I guess, your `InternalPair` has optional values and can be created from empty `JSON Object`. Try to declare it like `data class InternalPair(val first: String, val second: Long)` and check what would be the output. You can implement custom deserialiser and return empty `Pair` in that case.

Comment: In `Pair` I use nullable parameters as well...