# Jackson doesn't deserialize

Tags: java, json, serialization, fasterxml

I am struggling with deserializing with Jackson fasterXml.
I guess there is something about type information and polymorphic use.
I tried different things after reading jackson docs and [this](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com.es/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html) but still do not manage to get it. Serialization goes well but deserializing the produced string does not make it.

Thanks in advance for your help

Here is the classes :

```
   @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")  
private class DynReachSlotInternalRep {

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")

    private class ListStartStop extends MergeableLinkedList<DynTimeSlot> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    }

     private ListStartStop[] weekRep = new ListStartStop[7];

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public ListStartStop[] getWeekRep() {
        return weekRep;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void setWeekRep(ListStartStop[] weekRep) {
        this.weekRep = weekRep;
    }

    public DynReachSlotInternalRep() {
        super();

    }
/...



@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
public class DynTimeSlot extends IntervalComparison<DynTimeSlot> {

private int startHour;
private int startMinute;
private int stopHour;
private int stopMinute;


public int getStartHour() {
    return startHour;
}

public void setStartHour(int startHour) {
    this.startHour = startHour;
}

public int getStartMinute() {
    return startMinute;
}

public void setStartMinute(int startMinute) {
    this.startMinute = startMinute;
}

public int getStopHour() {
    return stopHour;
}

public void setStopHour(int stopHour) {
    this.stopHour = stopHour;
}

public int getStopMinute() {
    return stopMinute;
}

public void setStopMinute(int stopMinute) {
    this.stopMinute = stopMinute;
}

public DynTimeSlot(int startHour, int startMinute, int stopHour, int stopMinute) {
    super();
    if ((stopHour < startHour) || ((stopHour == startHour) && (startMinute > stopMinute)))
        throw new RuntimeException("Malformed timeslot");

    this.startHour = startHour;
    this.startMinute = startMinute;
    this.stopHour = stopHour;
    this.stopMinute = stopMinute;
}

public DynTimeSlot() {
    super();

}

/...

@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class")
public class MergeableLinkedList<A extends IntervalComparison<A>>  extends LinkedList<A> {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public MergeableLinkedList() {
    super();
    }


public void insert(A toInsert) {
    recursiveInsert(toInsert, this.listIterator());
}

public void delete (A toDelete) {
    recursiveDelete(toDelete, this.listIterator());
}
```

Here is the stack trace :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.dynamease.entity.DynReachSlot$DynReachSlotInternalRep]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
at [Source: java.io.StringReader@277b65b1; line: 1, column: 70]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:164)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:984)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:276)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:157)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:123)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:113)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:82)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeWithType(BeanDeserializerBase.java:894)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:36)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2034)
at com.dynamease.entity.DynReachSlot$DynTimeSlotOperations.getFromDirectoryRepresentation(DynReachSlot.java:145)
at com.dynamease.entity.DynReachSlot.<init>(DynReachSlot.java:53)
at com.dynamease.entity.DynReachSlotTest.test2(DynReachSlotTest.java:31)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type \[simple type, class \]: can not instantiate from JSON object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625783/jsonmappingexception-no-suitable-constructor-found-for-type-simple-type-class)

Answer (score 0):

From what you've posted, I think you're missing a [JsonCreator()](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html) for the `DynReachSlotInternalRep` class.

[Here](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_457.html)'s a nice tutorial.