# Map deserializing with Jackson in Java

Tags: java, json, generics, jackson

I have the following class

```
public class BetWrapper {

    private String description;
    private Calendar startTime;
    private HashMap<String, SimpleEntry<Integer, Double>> map;


    public BetWrapper() {
        map = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public Calendar getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(Calendar startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public HashMap<String, SimpleEntry<Integer, Double>> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(HashMap<String, SimpleEntry<Integer, Double>> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

}
```

And I'm using JSONUtil class

```
public class JSONUtil {

    private JSONUtil() {}

    public static <T> T fromJSON(String content, Class<T> clazz) throws TechnicalException {
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().readValue(content, clazz);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new TechnicalException(e);
        }
    }

    public static String toJSON(Object obj) throws TechnicalException {
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(obj);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
            throw new TechnicalException(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

I want to deserialzize a JSON to an BetWrapper object. But the following code produces some exceptions.

```
BetWrapper betWrapper = new BetWrapper();
betWrapper.setDescription("Stoke City - Arsenal");
betWrapper.setStartTime(Calendar.getInstance());
HashMap<String, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Double>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("home_team", new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(1, 2.85));
betWrapper.setMap(map);
String json = JSONUtil.toJSON(betWrapper);
JSONUtil.fromJSON(json, BetWrapper.class);
```

The exceptions are:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class java.util.AbstractMap$SimpleEntry<java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Double>]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
at [Source: {"description":"Stoke City - Arsenal","startTime":1417648132139,"map":{"home_team":"key":1,"value":2.85}}}; line: 1, column: 85] (through reference chain: by.bsu.kolodyuk.bettingapp.model.entity.BetWrapper["map"])
```

How to deserialize it correctly? It seems like that the problem is that types K,V in SimpleEntry should be specified for Jackson in some way.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Let's see `SimpleEntry`.

Comment: SimpleEntry is a static inner class of AbstractMap

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625783/jsonmappingexception-no-suitable-constructor-found-for-type-simple-type-class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type `SimpleEntry` has the following constructor

```
public SimpleEntry(K key, V value) {
    this.key   = key;
    this.value = value;
}
```

By default, Jackson expects a parameterless constructor. If such a constructor doesn't exist, it looks for one with `@JsonProperty` annotations. (I might have this backwards, but don't ever code like that.) Since you're working with a JDK type, it obviously won't have those annotations.

You can use Mixins. Jackson uses these as templates to deserialize your target type.

```
abstract class Mixin<K, V> {
    public Mixin(@JsonProperty("key") K key, @JsonProperty("value") V value) {}        
} 
...
public static <T> T fromJSON(String content, Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.addMixInAnnotations(SimpleEntry.class, Mixin.class);
    return mapper.readValue(content, clazz);
}
```

Jackson will use the meta type `Mixin`, to deserialize to `SimpleEntry` objects.

(Note, the type parameters of `Mixin` and the constructor parameter types don't really matter. It's the fact that there are two constructor parameters and that the constructor parameters are annotated that matters.)

Comment: Correct, with one minor change: `type` of constructor parameter does actually matter (name does not).

Comment: @StaxMan I tried this yesterday and it didn't complain. Maybe I wasn't doing what I thought I was. Let me try again.

Comment: @StaxMan So, yeah. I thought so too. But I just put some completely random types for the mixin constructor parameters and it still worked.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis interesting. It sounds like a bug actually. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Jackson, you can define custom deserializers. So for your case, it may look like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.AbstractMap;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;


public class SomeDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry>
{
    public SomeDeserializer()
    {
        super( AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.class );
    }

    @Override
    public AbstractMap.SimpleEntry deserialize( JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt ) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        Integer key = null;
        Double value = null;

        JsonToken token;
        while ( ( token = jp.nextValue() ) != null )
        {
            if ( token.isNumeric() )
            {
                String propertyName = jp.getCurrentName();
                if ( "key".equalsIgnoreCase( propertyName ) )
                {
                    key = jp.getIntValue();
                }
                else if ( "value".equalsIgnoreCase( propertyName ) )
                {
                    value = jp.getDoubleValue();
                }
            }
        }

        if ( key != null && value != null )
        {
            return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry( key, value );
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Deserializers should be registered using `ObjectMapper.registerModule(Module m)`. In your case, you can do it in your `JSONUtil` utility class:

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer( AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.class, new SomeDeserializer() );

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule( module );
```

Note that deserializer is registered with `ObjectMapper` instance. Thus you better store the instance as a field of your utility class.

*The deserializer class above is not comprehensive! This is just for demonstration for the case in hand. Further optimizations and refactorings can be applied as needed.*