# How to handle empty constructor with final fields

Tags: java, constructor, jersey, pojo, moxy

I have a class like this

```
 public class Test {

  private String m_username;

  public Test() {}

  public Test(String username) {
      m_username = username;
   }
}
```

And with Moxy. I can post this POJO to other API using Jersey client without any converting operation. But I need to set the m_username as a final field and that will need the empty constructor to initiate m_username. And also the Moxy doesn't work. How can I fix that?

Comment: *"But I need to set the m_username as a final field and that will need the empty constructor to initiate m_username"* So what's stopping you from doing that?

Comment: @HenlenLee please provide error trace of what you are getting.

Comment: @Andreas I need to keep m_username final, but I also need an empty constructor to let Moxy work. That's the problem I try to figure out.

Comment: Use Jackson instead with the `@JsonCreator`

Comment: [See if you use Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31094467/2587435); which IMO is much better for JSON than MOXy. And Jackson will still support almost all the MOXy (JAXB) annotations, so you might not have to make any changes to those.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't very well asked. 
AS far as I understand:

- You have to make your field final
- You have to keep the empty constructor because your object is automatically serialized/deserialized in a format like JSON, using a library such as those you can find in Spring

Unfortunately, these two constraints can't be held at the same time. You will need to abandon final if you want to keep the empty constructor, and conversely.

Comment: Yes. That's my question. It seems like I have to use another library to convert the POJO if the m_username is final

Comment: That's exact. POJOs that need to be automatically serialized/deserialized can't have final fields because they require your class to have a no-args constructor, as I have explained in my answer. You can't have both.