# Failed to instantiate com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments In MongoDB

Tags: json, spring, mongodb

[image]I'm using JsonNode for getting data from any kind of jason format and storing it to mongoDb
But  while fetching data from mongoDB it is throwing error as below.

`Failed to instantiate com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments`

Below is my domain class

```
public class Profiler {

 @Id
 private String id;

@Field("email")
private String email;

@Field("profiler")
private Map<String,JsonNode> profiler;

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public Map<String, JsonNode> getProfiler() {
    return profiler;
}
public void setProfiler(Map<String, JsonNode> profiler) {
    this.profiler = profiler;
}
public Profiler(String email,Map<String,JsonNode> profiler){
    this.email=email;
    this.profiler = profiler;
}
@JsonCreator
public Profiler(@JsonProperty("_id")String id,@JsonProperty("email")String email,@JsonProperty("profiler")Map<String,JsonNode> profiler){
    this.id=id;
    this.email=email;
    this.profiler = profiler;
}
public Profiler(String id){
    this.id=id;
}
public Profiler(Map<String,JsonNode> profiler){
    this.profiler = profiler;
}
public Profiler(){

}

}



public interface ProfilerRepository extends MongoRepository<Profiler, String>{
public Profiler findOneByEmail(String email);
}
```

And my controller call is as below and I'm getting the error on this line.

```
Profiler profile=profileService.findOneByEmail(email);
```

Comment: Can you show your mongo document?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have made this changes and work as expected.

```
Map<String, Object> profile;
```

Comment: You have a typo: `profile` -> `profiler`.

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs because `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode` class doesn't have default constructor (no argument constructor) and Jackson expects the default constructor.

[Related Post refer azerafati's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625783/jsonmappingexception-no-suitable-constructor-found-for-type-simple-type-class)

The problem can be resolved if you define the `profiler` field as static in domain class.

```
private static Map<String, JsonNode> profiler;
```

Please note that static fields have its own limitations and issues. I can assure that this would resolve the above exception. However, it may not be the most appropriate solution.

Comment: I tried the same but it not working. but i did one changes instead of JsonNode i have used Object like Map<String, Object> profiler; and working as exprected.

Answer (score 0):

in my case problem solved . i had entity that i defined :

```
private JsonNode data;
```

i changed it to:

```
private Map<String,String> data;
```

or this also work :

```
   private Map<Object,String> data;
```

please let me know if you had any question